# UWP WebView - Listener Event for OnScriptNotify failure

Tags: c#, windows, webview, uwp

I'm trying to add helpful error logging in our library to print out an error message if ScriptNotify fails due to the URI not being added to the app manifest.

This is the warning message printed within the WebView when I use DevTools to debug:

> DOM7010: Unable to receive a ScriptNotify event from: 'https://somerequireddomainhere'. The website attempted to send a ScriptNotify event to the app from a WebView URI that is not included in the ApplicationContentUriRules for this app. To permit this event, add the URI to the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the package manifest. (In Visual Studio, add this URI to the Content URIs tab of the Manifest Designer.)

I'm looking to expose a similar message somehow in the form of an error message in our library so it doesn't fail silently and gives a fellow developer a heads up on how to fix this.

Is there a listener or method that would get triggered in the event that ScriptNotify fails due to this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a listener or method that would get triggered in the event that ScriptNotify fails due to this scenario?

Currently there is not such event that could detect this error. We have indicated this in the official document, please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view#interacting-with-web-view-content). In my opinion, it is very useful. And if you want this event, please feel post it with windows feed back hub app.

Comment: Hi Nico, appreciate the clarity. Good to know that I'm not missing anything on my side.